# Writing a function in objective C that can automatically print something using the iphone keyboard in a text filed

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit

Hi people I have the following problem I have made an iphone application in which I have made the UI of the application using the interface builder and have a text field, a button and a label whenever a user enters some text in the text field and presses the button the message "Welcome : text field content" gets displayed in the label I have written the following IBAction for the button click

```
-(IBAction)updateText:(id)sender{

    NSString *text;

    if( [ textName.text length] == 0 )
    {
        text = @"Please Enter Your Name";
    }

    else
    {
        text = [ [NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello : %@" , textName.text ];
    }

    lblHello.text = text;

    [text release];

}
```

here textName is the name of the text field and lblHello is the label

but I want to automate this process of entering the text in the text field and pressing the button by writing some objective C function so that the values are entered automatically using the iphone keyboard and then the button is clicked. Can anyone help me write that function and where to call that function so that the task gets done. Please help me out with this and do tell if you need more code for reference.

Thanks in advance

Comment: yeah the objective C function should automatically enter the value we set in the method into the text field using the iphone keyboard and then press the button after that

Answer (score 2):

For this you should use the [UITextFieldDelegateMethods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html).
Have a look at:

`textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`

> The text field calls this method whenever the user types a new character in the text field or deletes an existing character.

For delegation you have to set the delegate of the textfield to your viewcontroller via code or Interfacebuilder. And you have to declare in your viewcontrollers header file that the class conforms to the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol.

As safecase mentioned you could use the delegate method

`textFieldDidEndEditing:`

too. The  difference between the to is the time when the label gets updated: `textFieldDidEndEditing:` is called after the editing in the textfield and `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` is called during typing.

Code:

In you .h file:

```
@interface YourClass : YourClassSuperClass <UITextFieldDelegate>

@propertys
-(void)someMethod;
@end
```

in your .m file you select the delegate method you'd like to implement for demonstrating I'll choose `textFieldDidEndEditing:`:

```
@implementation YourClass

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    textField.delegate = self;
}

#pragma mark - UITextFieldDelegate methods

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)aTextField {
    lblHello.text = aTextField.text;
}
```

If you like you can set `textField.delegate` via IB too. Don't forget to set the delegate or otherwise the delegate methods won't get called.

Please get familiar with the delegation pattern since it is often used! 
For more information how delegation works and how to use it you can read 
[Concepts in Objective-C Programming -> Delegates and Data Sources](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html)

Comment: I want to write an objective C function that when called automatically fills in the text field using the iphone keyboard and then presses the button its a type of automation that I am trying using the objective C :(

Comment: Added some example code. hope it helps! You should get familiar with the delegate pattern when coding Objecitve-C. It is very often used!

Comment: actually I am not much aware of objective C but have been assigned a task to do this can you write the complete snippet I think you are a professional iPhone programmer I can paste the entire code of my application here if you want :( :( :(

Comment: That's a great answer. I'd only change that delegation is not used just often. It is used (almost)always.

Comment: @Novarg but lets suppose I set a testcase that whenever I execute the application it should automatically enter "Coder" into the text field and then press the button the user shouldn't do this manually this is the problem I want to solve

Comment: @Coder and what will you do if you have to solve an similar problem? Take the time and understand how the delegate pattern is working since it will help you in the future too.

Comment: @Coder `[yourTextField setText:@"codr"];` in `viewDidLoad`, and call the method of your button on the next line. Seriously, if you got that assignment you should be able to do it. If you can't - read the books/docs/course materials. Or find another school/teacher

Answer (score 0):

Use UITextFieldDelegate method for this. When user will click on return button of iphone keyboard this method will be called:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

 if( [textName.text length] == 0 )
 {
   text = @"Please Enter Your Name";
 }

 else
 {
   text = [ [NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello : %@" , textName.text ];
 }

 lblHello.text = text;

}
```

Comment: Firstly can you tell how will this method add a string to the text field that I have set and when and how do I call this method and will this method also press the button that the user needs to press

Comment: it will automatically call when user will click on return button of iphone keyboard. just add this method in your code and check your @interface has <UITextFieldDelegate> set. Also use - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{ [textField resignFirstResponder];} delegate for using return keyword button to hide iphone keyboaed